# Error trying to compile in React Native: Failed to execute aapt

Tags: android, react-native, build, sdk

I get this error when trying to compile in React Native, I have fixed the version of the SDK in 27.0.3 and it does not work. Any ideas of what may be happening?

> Error:
>
> C:\Users\devan.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-
>
> 27.1.1.aar\750a91892d2e2f437e111b8d6039bfbe\res\values-v24\values-v24.xml:3:5-157:
>   AAPT: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches
>   the given name
>   'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Borderless.Colored'.
>
> C:\Users\devan.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.1.1.aar\750a91892d2e2f437e111b8d6039bfbe\res\values-v24\values-v24.xml:4:5-135:
>   AAPT: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches
>   the given name
>   'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Colored'.
>
> C:\Users\devan.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.1.1.aar\750a91892d2e2f437e111b8d6039bfbe\res\values-v26\values-v26.xml:13:5-16:13:
>   AAPT: No resource found that matches the given name: attr
>   'android:keyboardNavigationCluster'.
>
> ```
>  FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
> ```
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':react-native-orientation:verifyReleaseResources'.
>     com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute
>     aapt

My build.gradle:

```
android {


compileSdkVersion 27
buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.yojma"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 3
    versionName "3.0"
    ndk {
        abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
    }
}
signingConfigs {
    release {
        if (project.hasProperty('MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE')) {
            storeFile file(MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE)
            storePassword MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
            keyAlias MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
            keyPassword MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
        }
    }
}
splits {
    abi {
        reset()
        enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
        universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
        include "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
    }
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
}
// applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.each { output ->
        // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
        // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
        def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2]
        def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
        if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
            output.versionCodeOverride =
                    versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
        }
    }
}
}



dependencies {
    compile project(':react-native-orientation')
    compile project(':react-native-video')
    compile project(':react-native-vector-icons')
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.3"
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}
```

I've been trying to compile for a day. This has become very frustrating.

Comment: Were you able to solve this issue?

Comment: also having the same issue

Answer (score 0):

adding this to the project gradle file solved the issue for me:

```
subprojects {
  afterEvaluate {project ->
    if (project.hasProperty("android")) {
      android {
        compileSdkVersion 27
        buildToolsVersion "27.1.1"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

as per suggested here [React native Android Generate Signed APK giving Resource error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53435970/react-native-android-generate-signed-apk-giving-resource-error) which forces android subproject to use gradle build tool 27. 
My assumption is that some libraries in your project are using build tool version 26 or lower and this generates a broken apk. For example, I would check gradle build tool of react-native-orientation ':react-native-orientation:verifyReleaseResources'.

Answer (score 0):

**Before compiling or release build clean the build**

```
cd android
```

then

```
./gradlew clean
```

then

```
./gradlew app:assembleRelease
```