# React native Android Generate Signed APK giving Resource error

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, react-native-video

I have completed my android project on React Native and finding this error while compiling the project for Signed Apk.

```
> Task :react-native-video:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

error: resource android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Borderless.Colored not found.
error: resource android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Colored not found.
/Users/kedardave/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/appcompat-v7-27.1.1.aar/e10f37597a16932be24db019d75c890a/res/values-v26/values-v26.xml:9:5-12:13: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/colorError not found.

/Users/kedardave/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/appcompat-v7-27.1.1.aar/e10f37597a16932be24db019d75c890a/res/values-v26/values-v26.xml:13:5-16:13: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/colorError not found.

/Users/kedardave/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/appcompat-v7-27.1.1.aar/e10f37597a16932be24db019d75c890a/res/values-v26/values-v26.xml:17:5-93:AAPT: error: style attribute 'android:attr/keyboardNavigationCluster' not found.

/Users/kedardave/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/appcompat-v7-27.1.1.aar/e10f37597a16932be24db019d75c890a/res/values/values.xml:251:5-69: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/fontStyle not found.

/Users/kedardave/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/appcompat-v7-27.1.1.aar/e10f37597a16932be24db019d75c890a/res/values/values.xml:251:5-69: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/font not found.

/Users/kedardave/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/appcompat-v7-27.1.1.aar/e10f37597a16932be24db019d75c890a/res/values/values.xml:251:5-69: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/fontWeight not found.

error: failed linking references.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-keep-awake:verifyReleaseResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2m 42s
132 actionable tasks: 100 executed, 32 up-to-date
```

These are the problems I am getting, these are about resources and I don't know how to resolve it. It seems like Version issue with targetSDK but can't figure out

Answer (score 1):

Change supportLibVersion of build.gradle of your project to 27.1.1

**Edit**

How about adding below code to build.gradle of project,

```
subprojects {
  afterEvaluate {project ->
    if (project.hasProperty("android")) {
        android {
            compileSdkVersion 27
            buildToolsVersion "27.1.1"
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I have changed the support library build.gradle to 27.1.1 but still not working